# scrapy + tor always returns 403 but I can curl and browse

Tags: scrapy, tor, torsocks

I'm trying to setup `scrapy` + `tor`

I'm using scrapy 0.24.6

1. I first tried using `polipo` to be able to access `tor` as an http proxy (https://pkmishra.github.io/blog/2013/04/16/scrapy-run-using-tor-and-multiple-agents-part-2-ubuntu/)
   I'm able to configure my web browser to use polipo and I'm able to browse using TOR and I can curl.
   I tried `HttpProxyMiddleware` and using env var or writing my own custom middleware, same result: `scrapy` always returns 403
2. Then I tried to use `tor` directly, again I can configure my web browser to use the socks proxy and I can curl with `torsocks`, but `scrapy` always returns 403

Anyone has an idea about what might be wrong ?

It looks like the error come from `scrapy` because I have the exact same headers/user-agent with and without tor, but through tor I always get a 403